# A question on an isomorphism in a commutative diagram.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Consider the following commutative diagram of abelian groups where $f$ is an isomorphism and $g$ is a unique homomorphism.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{f}>> B\\
@VVV @VVV \\
C @>{g}>> D
\end{CD}$$

> Can I conclude that $g$ is also an isomorphism?

Comment: I think you need the vertical arrows to be isomorphisms as well. Then you can conclude that $g$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $A=B=C=\mathbb{Z}$ and $D=\{0\}$. There is a unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\{0\}$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}@>id>> \mathbb{Z} \\
@VidVV @V0VV \\
\mathbb{Z} @>0>> \{0\}
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: @user438991 I think the problem is ill posed.